# How to set default HTTP response headers and override them in the exception handler in Spring Boot Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception, response-headers

I have a controller annotated `@RestController` in Spring Boot (v2.4). This should return a HTTP header "Cache-Control" with a quite static configuration by default for all endpoints it handles.

Until now I achieved this with a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method inside the controller class that simply sets the headers like this:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void setResponseHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, 
    CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePrivate().getHeaderValue());
}
```

This works fine, but I found out that it collides a bit with my exception handler - I configured a global one by putting `@RestControllerAdvice` onto another class and then having multiple methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` for the various possible exceptions inside.

The exception handlers most of the time set a specific HTTP status of 400 and above and of course I don't want that to be cached.

Even if I make the `HttpServletResponse` available inside the exception handling methods, the HTTP headers are already set in there by my `setResponseHeader(HttpServletResponse)` method and the interface `HttpServletResponse` doesn't allow me to remove them again.

So is there any strategy to have the default caching headers on one side, but exceptions for the Exception handlers on the other side?

I really would appreciate if I don't have to set the caching headers individually inside my controller methods per endpoint.

Additional challenge is, that I need to stream big data to the client, so I really would like to avoid server-side caching because I expect lots of requests and want to prevent that the server fills its heap with the contents that should be delivered to the clients.
Unfortunately I cannot use the plain resource handler mechanism since complex queries regarding permissions (not just OAuth2, but licensing) are required that I don't want to put into a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries, I found this solution for my special situation:

- I stick to the `@ModelAttribute` to fill in default caching header.
- In the `@ExceptionHandler` annotated methods I overwrite the caching header with a "no-cache" value.

```
package test;

import org.springframework.http.CacheControl;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExHandlers {
  @ExceptionHandler({NullPointerException.class, IllegalStateException.class})
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public String nullPointer(RuntimeException e, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue())
    return e.getMessage();
  }
}
```

Important note: Don't use `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity` as this will add a second Cache-Control header to the response, while `HttpServletResponse.setHeader(...)` replaces the default one.
I checked the implementations and it is not possible to actively remove the header once it is set.

Downside of my solution: when the body has started to be streamed and an exception occurs, I cannot "revert" the headers - probably they have gone over the wire yet. But with the wish for no server-side caching I think that's the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This servlet filter sets the Cache-Control header, except when the response status is a 4xx error:

```java
public class CacheControlFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    var responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
    if (!HttpStatus.valueOf(responseWrapper.getStatus()).is4xxClientError()) {
      responseWrapper.setHeader(
          HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,
          CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePrivate().getHeaderValue());
    }

    responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
  }
}
```

You would also need to delete the other code that sets the header, because the header should be set in only one place.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. But I actually want to prevent server side caching - added a description of the additional challenge to the question :)